# NestJs EventBus duplicates event at EventHandler

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, nestjs, cqrs, kafkajs

I am trying out Event-Sourcing and CQRS using NestJs using Kafka as the Event Store.

The application is a small and simple one having 2 parts, customer and order. You first create a customer with some initial balance and then using the customer id you create an order, if the amount of the order is less than balance then it is approved otherwise rejected.

Here is the code in question: https://github.com/Ashniu123/nestjs-customer-order-eventsourcing-cqrs

I use KafkaJs as the EventBus (created my own [KafkaModule](https://github.com/Ashniu123/nestjs-customer-order-eventsourcing-cqrs/tree/master/libs/kafka) under `libs/`)

When I run this with Kafka and MongoDB, the app starts up just fine.
And when I create a customer too, the event `CreateCustomerEvent` is published as expected and pushed onto Kafka by the CommandHandler. (Checked using the landoop UI)

The problem comes in when the Event is read from Kafka and pushed onto the EventBus to be picked up and executed by the `EventHandler`. Like [CreateCustomerEventHandler](https://github.com/Ashniu123/nestjs-customer-order-eventsourcing-cqrs/blob/master/apps/customer-view-svc/src/events-handlers/create-customer.event-handlers.ts).

My configuration for EventBus to use Kafka is in AppModule for each service. For instance, [Customer](https://github.com/Ashniu123/nestjs-customer-order-eventsourcing-cqrs/blob/master/apps/customer-view-svc/src/app.module.ts#L40).

And the EventBus observable `subject$` is configured for the events in [KafkaService](https://github.com/Ashniu123/nestjs-customer-order-eventsourcing-cqrs/blob/master/libs/kafka/src/kafka.service.ts#L94).

Here are the application logs (added // for my comments).

customer-svc (Command side)

```
[Nest] 657306   - 09/13/2020, 12:54:47 AM   [CreateCustomerCommandHandler] Running command handler with: {"customerId":"900ee3e9-33aa-431c-bbd0-eea91cafb673","createCustomerDto":{"email":"someemail@gmail.com","password":"abc123","firstName":"john","lastName":"doe","balance":1000}}
[Nest] 657306   - 09/13/2020, 12:54:47 AM   [KafkaService] Published event: {"customerId":"900ee3e9-33aa-431c-bbd0-eea91cafb673","createCustomerDto":{"email":"someemail@gmail.com","password":"abc123","firstName":"john","lastName":"doe","balance":1000},"eventType":"CreateCustomerEvent"}
```

customer-view-svc (Query/View side)

```
[Nest] 657550   - 09/13/2020, 12:54:47 AM   [KafkaService] Bridged event payload value: {"customerId":"900ee3e9-33aa-431c-bbd0-eea91cafb673","createCustomerDto":{"email":"someemail@gmail.com","password":"abc123","firstName":"john","lastName":"doe","balance":1000},"eventType":"CreateCustomerEvent"}
[Nest] 657550   - 09/13/2020, 12:54:47 AM   [CreateCustomerEventHandler] Running event handler with: {"customerId":"900ee3e9-33aa-431c-bbd0-eea91cafb673","createCustomerDto":{"email":"someemail@gmail.com","password":"abc123","firstName":"john","lastName":"doe","balance":1000}}
[Nest] 657550   - 09/13/2020, 12:54:47 AM   [CreateCustomerEventHandler] Running event handler with: {"customerId":"900ee3e9-33aa-431c-bbd0-eea91cafb673","createCustomerDto":{"email":"someemail@gmail.com","password":"abc123","firstName":"john","lastName":"doe","balance":1000}}
[Nest] 657550   - 09/13/2020, 12:54:47 AM   [CreateCustomerEventHandler] Created customer: {"_id":"5f5d207f57cd5f089895867a","id":"900ee3e9-33aa-431c-bbd0-eea91cafb673","email":"someemail@gmail.com","password":"$2b$10$NzEnAHRsfh/7QnczB3p/MepPl0fD44G/6sFtzKsjpwudjYlNjGacG","firstName":"john","lastName":"doe","balance":1000,"salt":"$2b$10$NzEnAHRsfh/7QnczB3p/Me"}
[Nest] 657550   - 09/13/2020, 12:54:48 AM   [CreateCustomerEventHandler] Created customer: {"_id":"5f5d207f57cd5f089895867b","id":"900ee3e9-33aa-431c-bbd0-eea91cafb673","email":"someemail@gmail.com","password":"$2b$10$w0.mShhI3cMys7XAPLHRFusy63Fqlzj9s95JuSGdDpy.g5n5nt/8O","firstName":"john","lastName":"doe","balance":1000,"salt":"$2b$10$w0.mShhI3cMys7XAPLHRFu"}
// for some reason the another customer of same email is created even though in `customer.schema.ts` I have specified that it should be unique (not a priority at the moment)
```

What I could infer from the logs is that the Kafka event is received only once by the consumer as expected but is moved using `subject$.next` to the `EventHandler` twice.

Also, to clarify, the Events are pushed to the EventHandler two separate times, as suggested by the different values of the *customer._id* when created.

Using the debugger I could see that the `subject.observers` has 2 values in the array of class `FilterSubscriber`. I don't know if this is useful or no but just wanted to layout my efforts to cure this issue myself, and after 6 hours of nothing I have come here for help :).

I have added the launch.json to use with VSCode in the repo if you guys have better use of it. Just attach using the processId of the running application.

P.S. I have configured the EventBus of both `customer-view-svc` and `order-view-svc` in a similar manner and the issue exists in both (i.e. duplicate events). I hope that you guys will be able to help me resolve the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue, events published on the local event bus have their event handler called twice.
Is this question posted on the github repo of nestjs-cqrs?

Comment: @YousufKhan I have used an external bus- Kafka. Since you are also facing the issue, I have raised an issue on their github repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CQRS module registers the EventHandlers automatically by looking at the `providers` list. By using `EventBus.register()` we can add additional subscriptions.

This [commit](https://github.com/Ashniu123/nestjs-customer-order-eventsourcing-cqrs/commit/33f74487ff1286d1329d5ee9dfabb0972fc3a58e) resolves the issue.

By removing the EventHandlers list from `EventBus.register()`, I was able to subscribe to them only once and hence resolve the duplicate message issue.